# how to use mongoose aggregation to get sum of two matching documents depending on field

Tags: javascript, mongoose, count, aggregation-framework

I have two collections "Employee", "Office"

I am trying to find how many employees are in each area which contains office code.  But there might be more than one office in the same area.

This is how my Office documents might look like

```
[
  {
    _id: "5b7d0f77e231b6b530b0ee5a",
    code: "OB123456",
    city: "Canmore"
    // some other fields            
  },
  {
    _id: "5b7d0f77e531b6b530b0ee5b",
    code: "OB858758",
    city: "Vancouver"
  },
  {
    _id: "5b7d0f77e531b6b530b0ee5d",
    code: "EE858758",
    city: "Vancouver"
  },
]
```

this is how my Employee documents might look like

```
[
  {
    _id: "5b7d0f77e531b6b530b0edda",
    name: 'Charlie',
    office: {
      code: 'OB123456'
      // some other fields
    }
  },
  {
    _id: "5b7d0f73e531b6b530b0ee5b",
    name: 'Bill',
    office: {
      code: 'EE858758'
    }
  },
  {
    _id: "5b7d0f77e531b6b530b0ee5n",
    name: 'Echo',
    office: {
      code: 'OB123456'
    }
  },
];
```

I am looking into mongoose aggregate, and only tried

```
await Employee.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'offices',
          localField: 'office.code',
          foreignField: 'code',
          as: 'officeCode'
        },
        $group: {
          _id: 'officeCode.city',
          count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
    ]);
```

which for sure does not work, I tried reading some of the aggregation documention but cannot come up with a good idea how to get this done

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or advices.

Sample output of what I am looking for

```
{
    "Vancouver": 1,
    "Canmore": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start from office instead of employee, so you can create a list of code for each area (city), then lookup to map with your employees.

```
db.office.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$city",
      codes: {
        $addToSet: "$code"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "employee",
      localField: "codes",
      foreignField: "office.code",
      as: "employees"
    },
    
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: {
            $size: "$employees"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The two last stages are here only to format your result as described in your expected output.

[You can test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iIA3mZamMyO)